# CPU acceleration status: HAXM must be updated

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, haxm

I create a new virtual device in Android Studio. When I attempt to start it, I get the following error message:

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1024MB
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 384MB
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAXM must be updated (version 1.1.1 < 6.0.1).
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

You will need to actually *install* the Intel HAXM in order to use it:

### Windows

1. In your Android SDK folder, look in `extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\`
2. Run `intelhaxm-android.exe`

### Mac

1. Open the HAXM directory

   ```
   cd $ANDROID_HOME/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
   ```

   or, if `$ANDROID_HOME` is not set (i.e. if you're getting an error " No such file or directory"), try

   ```
   cd /Users/$USER/Library/Android/sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
   ```
2. Run the installer:

   - Mount the HAXM `*.dmg` file, then run the `*.mpkg` contained inside it

   or

   - Execute `$ ./silent_install.sh`

Comment: On macOS High Sierra, I get HAXM silent installation only supports macOS from 10.8 to 10.12

Comment: For the other newbies Android SDK path is C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\

Comment: @patrick depends on where it was installed, for me it was: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk. Also check if an older version is already installed. It doesn't uninstall it for you. Don't know what happens if you have multiple versions installed

Comment: I already had it installed through the SDK manager, but after running the EXE it updated to the newest version which solved all my issues.

Answer (score 35):

Goto **Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features**.

Look for Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager and check its version. In your case it should be 1.1.1 as seen from the error. Uninstall it.[image: This image is after installing the new version. Previously it was Version 1.1.1]

Go to this link (https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) to download the latest version.[image]

Run silent_install.bat which will install Intel HAXM's latest version. Now your Emulator should be working fine.

Answer (score 5):

So very simple. In your VS > Android Tools > check and install the option > "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (XAHM installer)"

[image: Visual Studio Xamarin Android HAXM installer]

Comment: It's helped me a lot, thanks for the screen shot .. Thumps up :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the tip, Just open the android studio and tools -> android SDK and you will see the SDK tools tab. you can select or update. If you see any update make sure you keep them up to date.

Answer (score -1):

You could also asign the AVD to use more memory.
This boosts it so much:

From Android studio open Windows->Select Android Virtual Device Manager->Chose your device->Click Edit button->Change the RAM parameter to 512 Mb in the Memory Options->Save and run the emulator it will work

Comment: Don't accept the answer for this question, see the last error "HAXM must be updated".