# Android Studio 3.1.2. AVD Incompatible HAX module version 3,requires minimum version 4

Tags: android-studio, android-virtual-device

```
19:58   Emulator: Incompatible HAX module version 3,requires minimum version 4

19:58   Emulator: No accelerator found.

19:58   Emulator: failed to initialize HAX: Invalid argument

19:58   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Missing initial data partition file: C:\Users\Wolfgang\.android\avd\SAMSUNG_S7_API24.avd/userdata.img

19:58   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

I recently updated my Android Studio version and since I work on the version 3.1.2. built 13.04.18 - shown in "About". My old device configured most likely on version 2.1 caused this error first, later I configured a new device with more or less the same parameters: API 24 (Nougat 7.0); Screen 5.1. and this device caused the above error protocol.

My OS is Windows 8.0.

Comment: This solution worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36880552/cpu-acceleration-status-haxm-must-be-updated

Comment: Thank you, Fulano, this solution I found before posting my question, but I did not find the 'android SDK folder' so I searched my whole hard disk for the program file 'intelhaxm-android.exe' and found out, that this file is located far away from the folders for the different versions of android studio: The path is

Comment: C:\Users\[YourUserName]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

Comment: But don't bother to find this programm file, it does not soluce the problem.

Comment: Yes, it values the pain to search for 'intelhaxm-android.exe' beause in the same folder there is a batchfile 'silent_install.bat' and this file is the one you should start, it will successfully soluce the problem. If not, you found more than one 'intelhaxm-android.exe', so you should try the batch-files in the other folders. Wolfgang

Comment: I've deleted the Latin introduction here - if it was important, please replace it with English.

Answer (score 12):

Goto Tools -> SDK Manager below screen will open

[image]

then select the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) and apply, it will install the HAXM

Comment: Uninstalling and installing what you have highlighted in yellow solved the problem for me, thank you. I also had to disable Hyper-V, because it conflicts with HAXM.

Comment: Works great for me

Comment: Uninstalling and re-installing the highlighted tool worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem here. After updating android studio to latest version i was asked to update

- Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)

now everything works fine.

Also check [how to install the Intel HAXM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36880666/10088459) and [how to find android sdk files location](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16582792/10088459)

Comment: Hi Giannis, I was not that luckily, most likely because I deinstalled my older version of Android Studio and then I downloaded the most recent Version. Meanwhile I had to change my computer and now the silent_install.bat has no effect, but the intelhaxm-android.exe I ran 2 times, because the first time I just had the option to uninstall HAXM the second time I could install a HAXM and now I don't have this error.

Comment: I was facing the same error from the original poster and it was solved by updating Intel HAXM, i.e. the first link from this answer. Consider yourself upvoted :)

Answer (score 6):

Here is what i did:

1. Go to  https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/ and download the latest release.
2. Install it.
3. Restart the emulator again.

That is what worked for me.

Comment: This also worked for Xamarin Android development, with the same error message.

Comment: This solves the error in Visual Studio Xamarin application. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me to install the new version HAXM

https://software.intel.com/en-us/android

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to $ANDROID_HOME/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

and run installer exe (intelhaxm-android.exe). after this everything will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

i was running Android Studio on windows and faced same error but after i seen referenced answer i realized that in some case we have to start HAXM installer manually in order to use it:

So Go to your Android SDK folder, in my case it was `C:\Users\[user's name]\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\` then there you will see `intelhaxm-android.exe` file,

Click on it and run it after finishing installation launch the `avd` device again then it will surely run (at least it ran in my case )

**NOTE:** if you are running it on Mac then see the Referenced answer it contains detail for windows and Mac Both.

ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36880666/10088459