# Getting error while running app on emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Whenever i'm trying to run my application on emulator. everytime i'm getting this error.

```
6:00 PM Emulator: Warning: Quick Boot / Snapshots not supported on this machine. A CPU with EPT + UG features is currently needed. We will address this in a future release.

6:00 PM Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsString!

6:00 PM Emulator: getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!

6:00 PM Emulator: Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!

6:00 PM Emulator: Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

6:00 PM Emulator: Incompatible HAX module version 3,requires minimum version 4

6:00 PM Emulator: No accelerator found.

6:00 PM Emulator: failed to initialize HAX: Invalid argument
```

I'm using Android studio version 3.2 .

Comment: `Incompatible HAX module version 3,requires minimum version 4` Have you tried updating HAXM to v4 and up ?

Comment: no, i don't known about haxm .

Answer (score 0):

Go to SDK Manager and update the `HAXM to >= v4` version. Or, on Android Studio:

```
Android Studio -> Tools -> SDK Manager
```

Updating to the v4 and up should solve the issue.

Check this link too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36880666/4409113